# Scheduled Load plan in ODI doesn't trigger automatically and needs manual intervention to run

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

Scheduled Load plan in ODI doesn't trigger automatically and needs manual intervention to run everyday. What could be the possible cause please?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Is the scheduling status set to Enabled? It should have a green checkmark icon in the Operator tab.
- Did you refresh the schedule of the agent (right-click on agent, select "Update schedule")?
- If you right-click the agent and select "View schedule..." does it show anything?

Comment: Thank you @Marco Baldelli... I have checked all the above points and they seem to be in check. Thanks